# OptaPlanner Right Tool for Scheduling of Manufacturing Orders

Tags: optaplanner

Would you consider OptaPlanner to be the right tool for the planning of manufacturing operations with multiple level routings (final product, subassembly1, subassembly2, subassembly11, subassembly12, ...)?

We are talking about several 1000s of manufacturing orders with 10-20 operations each.

Looks like project shop scheduling, I know. I'm just concerned a about the amount of data and the ability to find an optimal solution in a reasonable amount of time...

Are there real world examples for this problem domain and OptaPlanner out there?

Comment: I would sure consider OptaPlanner. Even if your problem scale is large, there are plenty of ways to break it up. Take a look at the docs for some inspiration. 

Here are some examples: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples

Answer (score 0):

See the [project job scheduling example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c). That's not our easiest or prettiest example, but it works and you can make it pretty.

For scaling, if it would end up as a problem (I doubt it for only 1k entities), there are plenty of power tweaking options (multithreaded solving, partitioned search, ...)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Well, it's 1k manufacturing orders (projects) times 10-20 operations (jobs) = 20k  that have to be planned, but it could be easily more... I would say 50k are quite realistic...

Comment: 50k, memory wise, won't be a problem to solve without partitioning (unlike in pretty much any other production constraint solver). But once it works, use optaplanner-benchmark to experiment with `<partitionedSearch>` for half of the available time. That's power tweaking. You 'll probably get better solutions in the same amount of time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! One more question: is there somewhere an example with resources having variable capacity over time (for example to exclude weekends, non-working times, etc.).

Comment: Does anyone have a hint for me?